# Sikulix/Python: RuntimeError when trying to load .dll

Tags: java, python, dll, ctypes

As mentioned in the title im getting a RuntimeError when trying to load a .dll in a sikuli script using ctypes.

```
import ctypes
path = %path to dll file%
mydll = ctypes.CDLL(path)
```

The error shows as follows:

```
[error] script (Test_ctypes) stopped with error in line 6
[error] RuntimeError (path)
[error] ---Traceback--- error source first
line: module (function) statement
262: __init__ (__init__) RuntimeError: path
6: main (<module>) mydll = ctypes.CDLL(path)
[error] ---Traceback --- end ---------------
```

I've tried the very same code in an anaconda build i have in another pc, and works fine, i can even interact with the functions within the .dll.

My guess would be an installation issue of some sort. As i don't have total control of the pc im running the script in, i'd need to know exactly the cause of the error, if possible...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention, if i use the function ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary, i get an almost identical error with the following variation:

`289:__init__ (LoadLibrary) File "path...\Sikulix\Extensions\jython-standalone-2.7.1.jar\Lib\ctypes\__init__", line 262, in __init__`

Comment: I can only tell you that `ctypes` support for `jython` may have issues while you are probably using `CPython` (Python standard implementation) with anaconda.